# Full screen height container Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can't get the container to stretch the **full height** of the screen:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid h-100" style="background-color:#0c5460;">
        a
    </div>
</body>
```

I tried the `h-100` and declaring `height:100%` and `min-height:100%` `container-fluid` and `container` but it never stretches beyond content that it contains

What am i missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Need

```
    html,body,.container {
        height: 100%;
    }
```